# Ant creates jar files in wrong destination

Tags: ant

Below is my build.xml file for ant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="Struts2ProductsDemo" default="jar">
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="L:\build" />
    <property name="project.name" value="Struts2ProductsDemo" />

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/classes" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean,makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}/classes" />
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">

    <jar destfile="${build.jar}/jars/${project.name}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}/classes" />
</target>
```

The jar files are created in: `C:\Users\San\EclipseWS\Struts2ProductsDemo\${build.jar}\jars\Struts2ProductsDemo.jar`

I am expecting the jar to be here: `${build.jar}/jars/${project.name}.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property `build.jar` is never set. You have to define it. For example, you may add this to your build:

```
<property name="build.jar" location="target"/>
```